# "Rewind" input on blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, css-selectors

I have an `input` with `text-overflow: ellipsis`. Is it possible to show the beginning of the text on `blur()`? Right now it stays at the end of the text where the cursor was.

Consider the following GIF trying to demonstrate the issue.

First, I focus the `<input>` and go the beginning of the input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>.  Then I go to the end of the `<input>` by focusing it again and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> and unfocussing.  You can see that the ellipsis is only there when my cursor is at the beginning of the input.

[image: Image showing ellipsis issue]

---

I might have just cracked it. Testing different browsers. Edit. Did not work properly in Safari. The `setSelectionRange` sets the focus back on the input on blur. Ideas?

```js
$("input").on('blur', function(e) {
  $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(0,0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="A bunch of text text text text text text text text text" style="width: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
```

Comment: what you tried so far?share the code

Comment: @NullPointer Added code. Read something about some browsers not supporting setSelectionRange. Is that old news?

Comment: Is it possible to show the beginning of the string on blur? means

Comment: can you explain a little about your problem

Comment: @NullPointer When the text overflows the input the view stays at the end of the text, not showing the beginning. I want it to say "A Lot of Text..." instead of "t of Text Here" on blur(). My code seems to have fixed it. Open to better solutions.

Comment: @SeaBass I have added a GIF to you question to try and show the issue effectively.  It was really difficult to understand at first from you description.  If you think the image is incorrect or if you don't want it in your question, please feel free to edit it back out.

Comment: @zero298 Awesome. Thanks. Side-note. What app did you use to make the gif?

Comment: @SeaBass Quicktime and ffmpeg.

Comment: canIuse says it has 94.41 %, https://caniuse.com/#search=setSelectionRange

Comment: If you cracked it then you can post it as an answer or remove the question if you don't want to post it

Comment: Hm, looks like it creates a loop in Safari where it sets focus again... Any way to set the selectionrange first and then blur without having the focus back on the input? Or is there a `scrollTop: 0` attribue I can use?

Comment: @Huangism do you know how to solve it for Safari as well? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to blur again when you need to, take a look at the below code and read comments to see what's going on

```js
// set true initially
var setRange = true;

$("input").on('blur', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  // set range then trigger blur again, change setRange flag
  if (setRange) {
    $this.get(0).setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    setRange = false;
    $this.trigger("blur");
  } else {
    // range was set before, reset the flag so it will work next time
    setRange = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="A bunch of text text text text text text text text text" style="width: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
```

Comment: Thank you! That gives me this error `"message": "too much recursion",`

Comment: And this: `"message": "Script error."`. However I just tried without the whole on blur part in Safari and it seems like it's now working without that hack so they probably fixed it in the latest version of Safari. Problem solved I guess. At least for new browser users.

Comment: Updated the answer, the flag setting should of gone before the blur trigger. It should work as intended now

Answer (score 2):

Works, but creates a loop in Safari where it sets focus again... Any way to set the selectionrange first and then blur?

```js
$("input").on('blur', function(e) {
  $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(0,0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="A bunch of text text text text text text text text text" style="width: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
```

Comment: Any Ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if anyone has an idea how to solve this in safari?

Comment: It's ok to blur first then set range then blur again. You just need to define a variable as a flag so once you set the range, then trigger blur manually. On the second round manually triggered blur, you can check for the flag to know if you need to set range again. If range is already set, then reset the flag and do nothing